# Different screen size edits doesn't match

Tags: java, android

Problem is, I can make different screen sizes for my activitys, but still NORMAL-size looks different in some devices. I am using Nexus 5 as emulator and preview and everything looks fine, but when I enter my real phone, Galaxy J5 (screen size should be same as the Nexus 5 (1080x1920)), some imageviews are in the incorrect places. This same happends in NExus 6P and some other devices...

Is the problem in the density, resolution? If yes, then is there guides to make them match...

Comment: see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36820746/how-to-design-any-screen-size-and-density-in-androidmulti-screen-for-mobiles/36821546#36821546) this will help you to design your activity

Comment: It doesn't help... sorry

Comment: sorry but you cant read all of them in 10 mins!

Comment: First of all... That information shows me all about screen density and stuff that I mostly already know But doesn't help me further with my problem