# Changing the orientation switches the layout used when designing

Tags: android, android-layout

Wondering if anyone has ran in to this.

I have created layout folders with 5 resource qualifiers.

- sw320dp
- sw480dp
- sw600dp
- sw720dp
- sw800dp

I also have 5 drawable folders with resource qualifiers from mdpi through xxxhdpi.

My goal is to have my application function on all devices (minus small) with smallest width of `320` and any density.

I am 90% of the way there and have ran in to an issue which I have been unable to resolve.  My guess is that I have an issue with resource qualifier precedence , but that is only a guess.

The issue I am running in to is this.  I can double-click on ANY of my layouts in any of the different layout folders and it will bring up the layout using an appropriate device within Android studio designer given the `sw<n>dp` layout that I selected.  For example, if I double-click on my main_activity layout that is in the `sw600dp` folder, it opens using the 7" tablet and everything is good.  This holds true for every layout I have in every layout folder, with the exception of ONE layout within my `layout-sw480dp` folder.

When this particular layout is opened, it opens up in Portrait mode via the Nexus 4, when it should have launched one of the `sw480` devices instead.  If we look at the specs of the Nexus 4, it is as follows.

`768 x 1280 / hdpi`

So, this means that the smallest width of this device would be `768 / 2 = 384`, which falls in to the `sw320dp` bucket.

If I then select one of the sw480dp devices, such as the Nexus 6p, which has the following specs, `1440 x 2560` `560dpi` which in turn has a smallest screen width of `1440 / 3 = 480`, it opens using a layout in the `sw320dp` folder.

Again, this is the ONLY layout file that is doing this out of ALL of them.

If anybody has any suggestions or has ran across this type behavior in the past, I would love to hear what you did.

Comment: HDPI is not 2x, it's 1.5x. So the sw of the Nexus 4 ist 512dp.

Comment: see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36820746/how-to-design-any-screen-size-and-density-in-androidmulti-screen-for-mobiles/36821546#36821546)

Comment: Correct, typo on my part.  This has gotten a bit more odd.  I have attempted to simplify things by moving to a single set of layout files for my app (no qualifiers).  I believe I should be able to do this since my layouts that I had been putting in each of the different layout-qualifier folders were identical.  I do have some size and placement differences that need to be accounted for given screen size and density, so for that I am still using my values-sw<n>dp-<density> folders.

Comment: Update.  The issue seems to be that when selecting the 5x/6/6p devices in Android studio, they are trying (but failing) to use the values-sw320dp-hdpi folder, which is wrong for all three.  I have come to this conclusion because the layout in question is getting a value for textsize of 99 which I specifically put in my hdpi version to see if that is actually what was getting pulled.