# integer,xml screen size wise

Tags: android, dimensions

I know this kind of question has been asked many times but none of them helped me.

I want different integer values for my 4, 5 and 5.5 inch devices. For that I have created different values folder like `values-small`, `values-normal` and `values-large`

But every time I am getting value from `values-normal` only. None of this work for me.

I have also tired to calculate minimum width using following formula. To get minimum width and create folder accordingly.

```
DisplayMetrics dm = this.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float screenWidth = dm.widthPixels / dm.density;
float screenHeight = dm.heightPixels / dm.density;
```

Still I am getting same result. Please help me to figure this out.

My testing devices are HTC ONE X(4.7 inch), Moto G3(5 inch) amd Meizu MX5 (5.5 inch)

Comment: Please, explain. what values are incorrect?

Comment: first i have tried with values-smal,normal etc but i am getting value from normal in all devices...then i turned to calculate sw but steel sw is same for all devices

Comment: have you tried to use `values-ldpi`,`/values-mdpi`?

Comment: no i am trying that...give me some time

Comment: didnt help....steel getting same result

Comment: so, explain namely results you want to retrieve.

Comment: why do you calculate display metrics?

Comment: sorry! cant get you

Comment: to get sw width and to create folder accordingly

Comment: What does 'sw width' mean? please, make your question more clear.

Comment: smallest width of device...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why but i was getting same smallest width for my HTC (4.7) and 
Moto3G (5). So i switched to heard coding it.

well for now i have solved this with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36820746/how-to-design-any-screen-size-and-density-in-androidmulti-screen-for-mobiles/36821546#36821546). I am calculating smallest width at run time and get my desired output using if..else. I dont know this is the best solution or not, but working for me at this time.

Looking for batter solution or suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating folder as below.

```
res/values/dimens.xml(default)
res/values-ldpi/dimens.xml   (240x320 and nearer resolution)
res/values-mdpi/dimens.xml   (320x480 and nearer resolution)
res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml   (480x800, 540x960 and nearer resolution)
res/values-xhdpi/dimens.xml  (720x1280 - Samsung S3, Micromax Canvas HD, etc) 
res/values-xxhdpi/dimens.xml (1080x1920 - Samsung S4, HTC one, etc)
```

it's working fine for me

Comment: i am getting result from xhdpi...for all three devices